# SlidingPaneLayout setting sub-control width is invalid, display as full screen

Tags: android

SlidingPaneLayout setting sub-control width is invalid, display as full screen，use the lib:    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'

in xml.file,is invalid

SlidingPaneLayout can control the width of the left and right controls，thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.